# move UIslider based on text field value

Tags: swift

I have a form with a slider and a text field. I want the user to be able to enter the value using the keyboard and the slider to move based on the value.

I want to be able to change the value using the slider as well. This works. But when I try entering the value using a keyboard my app crashes. The error given is " Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Code Within View Did Load

```
   orgDiscounttxt.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("chgTextFieldDidChange:")), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

//// please outside view did load

```
 func chgTextFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField)
{
    if let chgStringValue = orgDiscounttxt.text
    {
        if let chgIntValue = Int(chgStringValue)
        { chgDiscountSlider.setValue(Float(Double(chgIntValue)), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

//Controlls slider that changes text field value

```
  @IBAction func mortgageDiscountSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {

    orgDiscounttxt.text = String(format: "%.2f",Double(sender.value))


}
```

[image: Linked outlets]

Comment: It seems your outlets are correctly connected. Please try to inform the exact line the error occurs and the complete message on the console. Also, probably not related but I'd recommend changing `Selector(("chgTextFieldDidChange:"))` for `#selector(chgTextFieldDidChange(textField:))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Fixed OP's problem**

Replace `Selector(("chgTextFieldDidChange:"))` for `#selector(chgTextFieldDidChange(textField:))`.

**Original and most commom answer:**

The `Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` message is usually related to some problem in the connection between the XIB or Storyboard with the IBOutlet. Check if the connections are ok in the panel as follows:

[image]

Comment: As posted in the image above the outlets are not showing under 'SearchDispalyController' Is this my problem, if so, how do I link the outlet this way

Comment: The code edit you posted fixed the problem. now to figure out how to trigger an error message if the user enters a value greater than 3.  Thank you